# Setting text labels to the difference in time intervals

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nsdate

I'm trying to set a text label to the time difference between two objects; the current time and a saved time in Parse. My issue is with the if/else statement at the end. The labels are all assigned with either the datesHours or datesMinutes dictionaries whereas the datesHours dictionary should be assigned only when hours is greater than 1- otherwise, the text label should show the number of minutes.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
 var datesHours = [Int: String]()
 var datesMinutes = [Int: String]()



      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell") as! TableViewCell

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Items")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects {
                for (index, title) in enumerate(objects) {
                    let itemDate = (title as! PFObject)["date"] as! NSDate

                    var timeDifference = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(itemDate)
                    var time = Int(timeDifference)
                    var minutes = ((time / 60) % 60)
                    var hours = (time / 3600)

                    self.datesHours[index] = String(hours)
                    self.datesMinutes[index] = String(minutes)
                    //println(self.datesMinutes)
                    //println(self.datesHours)

                    for (index, hour) in self.datesHours {

                    if hour == "\(0)" {
                        cell.timeLabel.text = self.datesMinutes[indexPath.row]! + "m"

                        } else  {
                        cell.timeLabel.text = self.datesHours[indexPath.row]! + "hr"
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is correct, and you have a set of dictionaries that need to be displayed on your cell. Try this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[mArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"HOUR OR MINUTE KEY"];
```

Comment: Yeah, the data's correct. The issue is with assigning the hour dictionary or minutes dictionary depending on whether time is over an hour or not. If under an hour, minutes dictionary should be used on the specific item (text label) otherwise the hour dictionary should be used.

Comment: So the data is correct but it's not being displayed on your labels?

Comment: No it is being displayed. But either the hours or minutes dictionary are applied to all the labels whereas they should be applied to each specific label according to the criteria ( over 1 hour = hours dictionary for that label but if another label is under an hour, then minutes dictionary should apply)

Comment: Well I'll have to go though it more , I'm at lunch. But your if else is saying if hours of greater than one apply to all cells. You need to iterate over all the hours and minutes and assign after that. Maybe check if hours.indexpath assign else minutes assign

Comment: Appreciate your help. I updated my question. I added a for loop to iterate through the hours dictionary but it's just showing the hours dictionary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86723/discussion-between-theactuary-and-mkane).